# How to make vuex modules $store references in .vue components

Tags: vue.js, vuex

**Summary:** Can Vuex modules be made $store references in .vue components (instead of referring to the Global Store as it is now after `Vue.use(Vuex)`) ?

**Details:**

I read this: [vuex modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html) and I get that the global store can be composed as a bunch of vuex modules.

This is great but is there also a way to make these vuex modules the $store references within vue components instead of $store pointing to the global store (as it is now ?).

This will be mighty useful (IMO) since vue components then have to only be aware of its local store's references (or their own vuex modules); and, how they compose the global store.

Please advise.

Comment: Vuex is for managing state across various components. If you want different components  to  be aware of its local store's references only you can use the component's local state itself, why vuex?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna, I am not referring to a local vuex state instances as referred here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html#components-can-still-have-local-state. I would like the global state's modules to be available as local states ( as `$state`) for each .vue component; and, if there is a means to do so. WDYT ...

Comment: You should look at `mapState`. https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html#the-mapstate-helper